# Why does my ajax success callback-function not work as expected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I code this ajax request but I don't know why the code in the success method doesn't work

Even though in the networks in chrome browser appear state: 200ok

[image: img]

this is ajax code:

```
$("#noti_filter").click(function(){
  //first add item into cart
  var item_id = 'test';
  $.ajax({
    method:"POST",
    //contentType:"application/json",
    url:"../html/notifies.php",
    data:{product_id:item_id},
    dataType: "json",
    success:function(data,state) {
      console.log(data);
      console.log(state);
      alert('ajax success');
    }
  });
});
```

the problem is that alert or console Not to mention the others code

```
  success:function(data,state)
  {
    console.log(data);
    console.log(state);
    alert('ajax success');

  }
```

Comment: Look in the console. Add an error handler

Comment: Make sure you set your console filter to show log messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [ajax events](https://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/) docs:

> success (Local Event)
>
> This event is only called if the request was successful (no errors from the server, no errors with the data).

Since your server responded with `200 OK` that means we can route out problems with the server and are left with errors with the data.

From the [ajax](https://api.jquery.com/Jquery.ajax/) docs (only the relevant parts):

> dataType
>
> The type of data that you're expecting back from the server.
>
> The available types (and the result passed as the first argument to your success callback) are:
>
> "json": Evaluates the response as JSON and returns a JavaScript object.
> ...
> The JSON data is parsed in a strict manner; any malformed JSON is rejected and a parse error is thrown. As of jQuery 1.9, an empty response is also rejected; the server should return a response of null or {} instead. (See [json.org](https://json.org) for more information on proper JSON formatting.)

So most likely the data returned by the server is being rejected by ajax in which case a parse error should be thrown.

This would be an example of how to implement an error handler:

```
$("#noti_filter").click(function(){
    //first add item into cart
    var item_id = 'test';

    $.ajax({
       method:"POST",
       //contentType:"application/json",
       url:"../html/notifies.php",
       data:{product_id:item_id},
       dataType: "json",
       success: function(data,state) {
           console.log(data);
           console.log(state);
           alert('ajax success');
       },
       error: function(err) {
           console.log(err.responseText);   // <-- printing error message to console
       }
    });
});
```

Comment: its work i change the datatype to html  but there another problem has shown up  in the result.php page where i recieve the posted data      this is the page content                                   <?php if(isset($_POST['data'])){$data=$_POST['data']; echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>'.$data.'</div>";}

?>                  it doesn't echo the data;

Comment: @yahyahaddad If you change your datatype back to `json`, you will receive it on the server as `$_POST['data']` and then you have to `json_decode()` it like this: `$data = json_decode($_POST['data'])`. Check [here](https://www.w3schools.com/Php/php_json.asp) for examples of how to decode json on in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

You defined the dataType as `json`. The `dataType` is the type of data that you're expecting back from the server. Does your server responds `json`?

I assume the result of your 200-ok-server-request is probably not in `json` format, so the parsing fails and your `success`-callback is not called. You can catch the error with `error` callback function.
After that you know the exact reason.

Comment: ok how i can make the result in json format

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064444/returning-json-from-a-php-script